# алгоритм Quick Sort

Tags: c++

как написать алгоритм Quick Sort?

Comment: Главное - правильно написать :)

Comment: И там (по ссылке) и тут (в скопипасченном ответе) убогая реализация. В нормальной рекурсивной реализации, после разбиения массива **сначала** надо сортировать **короткую** часть (тогда стек никогда не переполнится). Ну, еще можно порассуждать о правильном выборе разделяющего элемента, который минимизирует вероятность сползания сложности алгоритма к квадратичной

Answer (score 0):

Плохо ищете. В интернете полно статей. Код взял из [Quick Sort](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort)

```
void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
  int i = left, j = right;
  int tmp;
  int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

  /* partition */

  while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot)
              i++;
        while (arr[j] > pivot)
              j--;
        if (i <= j) {
              tmp = arr[i];
              arr[i] = arr[j];
              arr[j] = tmp;
              i++;
              j--;
        }
  };

  /* recursion */

  if (left < j)
        quickSort(arr, left, j);

      if (i < right)
            quickSort(arr, i, right);
}
```

Comment: что тут делает это строка   int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];?